# Method for Dismissing a UIAlertView

Tags: ios

I was wandering if it was more correct to dismiss a UIAlertView using:

```
[alert removeFromSuperview];
```

Or using:

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex: 0 animated: TRUE];
```

The first one seems to give problems...

Comment: alert is a popup view so should be dismissed using `[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex: 0 animated: TRUE];`

Comment: More correctly it should be: `[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:alert.cancelButtonIndex animated:YES];`. `BOOL` values should be either `YES` or `NO`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alert is a popup view so should always be dismissed using `[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex: 0 animated: YES];`

Answer (score 2):

Always use dismissWithClickedButtonIndex. Removing the view from the superview has undefined behaviour - we have no idea what the iOS internals are doing.